# Can a C++ class contain a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

So, I was trying to instantiate an object of a class containing a vector in C++, and compiler gave me an incomplete type error. I have simplified the code to as follows:

```
#include <vector>
class Test;
int main(){Test vector;}
class Test{ std::vector<int> vector;};
```

I am assuming that this is because the vector is not of a defined size, so the computer doesn't know how to allocate memory for it. How do I get around this issue? Sorry for the beginner question.

Comment: It would make the code more readable and understandable if you named your variable something other than `vector`.

Comment: C++ class can contain ```vector```, but class definition need to be before ```main```. Your error has nothing to do with that your class contain a ```vector```.

Comment: You didn't simplify the test case enough. You can eliminate the `std::vector<int> vector;` and you still get the same error. That should tell you something. When simplifying code keep going till the problem goes away ant then take one step back and consider that last step carefully.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you put the class definition after it's first use. Try putting the class definition before the first use, like this

```
#include <vector>
class Test{ std::vector<int> vector;};
int main(){Test vector;}
```

This has nothing to do with vectors, you would get the same error without a vector.

And of course it's perfectly possible to put a vector inside a class. They would be all but useless if you could not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but remember that calling the class variable std::vector<> "vector" and calling the object itself "vector" will lead to much confusion.

```
#include <vector>

class TestClass{
public:
    std::vector<int> vector;
};

int main() {
    TestClass obj;
}
```